# Ambigous situation when using varargs

Tags: java-7, variadic-functions

I have two methods:

1. addMsg(String summary, String msg, Object... params)
2. addMsg(String msg, Object... params)

Which one will be called when execute *addMsg("str1", "str2", "str3")* ?

Can I choose which one to be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which one will be called when execute addMsg("str1", "str2", "str3") ?

The long version will be called:

```
public void addMsg(String summary, String msg, Object... params)
```

> Can I choose which one to be used?

If you really can't change the method names to have an intention-revealing name or change the signature by changing the types (e.g. you are dealing with a legacy application), you can always invoke the short version by using reflection:

```
Method hiddenMethod = Arrays.stream(this.getClass().getDeclaredMethods())
                         .filter(method -> "addMsg".equals(method.getName()))
                         .filter(method -> method.getParameterTypes().length == 2)
                         .findFirst()
                         .orElseThrow(IllegalStateException::new);

Object[] params = { "message" , new String[]{"param1", "param2"}};

hiddenMethod.invoke(this,params);
```

But **never do this if you can avoid this scenario**.

Comment: Thanks for clear answer though it takes me time to learn about java 8

Answer (score 0):

I actually think this is a misuse of varargs. 
What I suggest you to do is

```
addMsg(Integer type, Object... params)
```

You'd better differentiate the treatment to do using a different variable (integer, as I proposed).

Comment: Yes, I think it is a misuse but if it doesn't get a Warning, may be there is a way